# Scroll to find element nested inside - Senium with Python (using SeleniumLibrary)

Tags: python, selenium, react-scroll

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

I need to find element "16" , my project using `driver = SeleniumLibrary`

```
driver.open_browswer("..."_
driver.find_element ("//div[@id='react-select-4--value']").click()
driver.scroll_element_into_view("//span[contains(text(),'16']")
driver.find_element("//span[contains(text(),'16']").click()
```

I could click on the react-dropdown list but I can't use `scroll_element_into_view` to find that element then click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
option = driver.find_element("//span[contains(text(),'16')]")
driver.execute_javascript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", option)
```

Could you try this,

Comment: option = test.driver.find_element("//span[contains(text(),'16']")
--->
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[contains(text(),'16']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @Scorpisces i just copy pasted locator from your question , it was missing a bracket updated now

Comment: It show a list 0, 1,2,3,... and resonse that the xpath can't found.
I think I can use:
`driver.find_element('xpath').send_keys("16")` -> and try to `send_key(Keys.RETURN)` but It needs a locator to send_keys 
`driver.find_element('xpath').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)"` or `r"\ue007"` not work

Comment: `Exception: Error 'SeleniumLibrary' object has no attribute 'execute_script'` @PDHide

Comment: use execute_javascript

Comment: It only expand a dropdown 0 1 2 3 4 5 and resonsed: `Exception: Error Element with locator '//span[contains(text(),'16')]' not found.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227374/discussion-between-scorpisces-and-pdhide).

Answer (score 1):

If there is input element you can directly send '16' like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_of_element').send_keys(16)
```

and If there is Option element then you can select using following method

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

element = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='react-select-4--value']"))
element.select_by_value("16")
```

Comment: when I send_keys(16) It showed line 16 but It looks like a suggestion, I need "enter" or click on the line to choose.
But after send_keys(16) and send_keys(Keys.RETURN) it can't find the that xpath, the input xpath

Comment: It seems not having "option" to select and with SeleniumLibrary I don't know how to call Select @@